# How do I conditionally format a range of cells based on another range of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to conditionally format `J1` if the range  `K1` to `U1` is blank.

I've tried `=ISBLANK(K1:U1)` and it is only triggering if B is not blank.

Comment: Are you looking for if any are blank or all need to be blank?

Comment: @ScottCraner either would work I can just change the format colour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to count the number of cells that are not blank:

```
=COUNTA($K1:$U1)<11
```

Will highlight all rows where one or more cells are blank

While:

```
=COUNTA($K1:$U1)=0
```

Will highlight all rows with all cells empty

And:

```
=COUNTA($K1:$U1)>0
```

Will highlight all rows with some content

Finally:

```
=COUNTA($K1:$U1)=0
```

Will highlight rows where all cells are filled

Comment: I think this should be the other way around?  `=COUNTA($K1:$U1)>0`?

Comment: @Chronocidal - Yes, edited my answer to cover four scenarios

Comment: Thank you for the breakdowns! This was really annoying!

Answer (score 0):

`ISBLANK()`does not expect a range, but a single cell.

Should be:
`=AND(ISBLANK(K5),ISBLANK(L5),ISBLANK(M5))` all the way to U5

Comment: Forgive my lazyness :P